# Performing GET requests (with parameter) in pytest

Tags: python, flask

I have written an endpoint in my flask server, that when triggered, with a GET request, and a parameter, the server will parse the parameter, and serve the file (specified in the parameter) to the user to download.

This is the server's code:

```
@app.route('/getfile', methods=['GET'])
def dl_file():
   requestedFile = request.args.get('id')
   allFiles = os.listdir('myFiles')
   if requestedFile not in allFiles:
      return make_response(json.dumps({'error_message': 'item does not exist'}), 400)
   else:
      return send_file(pathAndFilename, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename = requestedFile)
```

I am able to trigger this with:

```
curl -X GET "0000:5000/getfile?id=myFile.txt"
```

How do i trigger this in pytest?

But i do not know how to pass the parameter in the GET request, and how to grab the server's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass those parameters as you do when performing curl requests, ie.

```py
response = client.get('/getfile?id=myFile.txt')
```

Alternatively, you can use Python's standard library, [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) and its `urlencode` method.

```
In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: data = {'id': 'myFile.txt'}

In [3]: urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
Out[3]: 'id=myFile.txt'
```

This can be combined together:

```py
import urllib

@pytest.mark.parametrize("filename, status, error_message_template", [
        ('myFile.txt', 200, 'null'),
        ('does_not_exist.txt', 400, 'item does not exist')
            ])

def test_dl_file(change_directory, filename, status, error_message_template):
   client = app.test_client()
   data = {"id": filename}
   query = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
   response = client.get('/getfile' + query)
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the parameter is not always a string, but a variable?

Comment: @user1584421 I've updated the answer. You can automate this proces now ;-)

Comment: Thank you! But still, how do i trigger the server with a GET request, in the specified endpoint and still use urllib.parse.urlencode()?

Comment: @user1584421 I've updated the answer. Is it more clear now?

Comment: For some reason, when i trigger the server like this from pytest, i always get `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on the server`. I don't know why.

Comment: Check the path you pass to the client. Query parameters should not be able to give 404.